# Printing a field value in an array

Tags: php

I'm using the tutorial found [here](http://www.nmcmahon.co.uk/using-the-google-maps-directions-api-to-calculate-distances/) to display the directions based on Google Maps Directions API in Drupal. I have two fields in my node - originfield and destinationfield. Each of them contains the name of a city.

The problem is that I can't print the field value inside of the $params array. Here is the whole tpl.php code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Returns the HTML for a node.
 *
 * Complete documentation for this file is available online.
 * @see https://drupal.org/node/1728164
 */
?>

<?php
// This print works:
print $node->field_originfield['und'][0]['value'];

    // Parameters used for the request
    $params = array(
        'origin'    => 'Tokyo, Japan', // I can't find a way to output the originfield's value here
        'destination'   => 'Kyoto, Japan' // I can't find a way to output the destinationfield's value here
    );

    // Join parameters into URL string
    foreach($params as $var => $val){
        $params_string .= '&' . $var . '=' . urlencode($val);  
    }

    // Request URL
    $url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?".ltrim($params_string, '&');

    // Make our API request
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $return = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    // Parse the JSON response
    $directions = json_decode($return);

    // Show the total distance
    print('<p><strong>Total distance:</strong> ' . $directions->routes[0]->legs[0]->distance->text . '</p>');

?>

// This print works:
<?php
print $node->field_originfield['und'][0]['value'];
print $node->field_destinationfield['und'][0]['value'];
?>
```

If I manually add origin and destination everything works fine. But if I use any of the following combinations, the whole page gets either messed up and nothing is displayed or nothing happens at all.

```
'origin'    => "<?php print $node->field_originfield['und'][0]['value']; ?>"
'origin'    => "print $node->field_originfield['und'][0]['value'];"
'origin'    => "$node->field_originfield['und'][0]['value'];"
'origin'    => "field_originfield['und'][0]['value'];"
'origin'    => "field_originfield;"
'origin'    => "<?php print render($content['originfield']); ?>"
```

I have also tried this, without luck:

```
$departure = print $node->field_originfield['und'][0]['value'];
$arrival = print $node->field_destinationfield['und'][0]['value'];

'origin' => 'departure',
'destination'   => 'arrival'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Start by doing a `print_r($directions)` just after the `$directions = json_decode($return);` then you will see what the data structure looks like

Comment: Also use `$departure = $node->field_originfield['und'][0]['value'];` the `print` bit is not doing what you may think

Comment: @RiggsFolly That part is fine, I can print the directions and distance. The problem I'm having is that I'm not telling the script the right way what are the origin and destination cities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
$params = array(
    'origin'    => $node->field_originfield['und'][0]['value'],
    'departure' => $node->field_destinationfield['und'][0]['value']
);
```

or

```
$departure = $node->field_originfield['und'][0]['value'];
$arrival = $node->field_destinationfield['und'][0]['value'];

$params = array(
    'origin' => $departure,
    'destination'   => $arrival
);
```

Comment: The first one didn't work, but the second one did. Thank you! I'll accept the answer in few minutes, it's not possible to accept it yet. Could you point me where I could learn more about this part of php?

Comment: Glad i could help! Sure: the keywords to look for are "array access" "object access". The questions are "How to work with an array?" and "How to work and access data in an object?" and "How to work with multi-dimensional arrays and objects?". For array access: http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php For object property access: http://php.net/manual/de/language.oop5.properties.php Don't get overwhelmed by the amount of information there. Pick what you need and go step by step.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$departure = $node->field_originfield['und'][0]['value'];
$arrival = $node->field_destinationfield['und'][0]['value'];

'origin' => $departure,
'destination'   => $arrival
```

Comment: Thank you. This does work, but the other part has to be part of the array.